# How to test private methods from Boost tests?

Tags: c++, testing, boost

I am running into a frustration with testing with Boost, and I am wondering if there is a cleaner/better way to handle it.

I have some method *myFunc()* which is a part of *MyClass*.

- *myFunc()* really should be private - it's for internal use by *MyClass* only, nothing else needs to be aware of it or use it.
- I must test *myFunc()*. It is a small, but important part of the larger class. If it fails, the functionality of the class is wrong for some usages.

However, this is where we hit the problem:

- Boost test cases (Set up with `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE`, `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE`, etc) cannot access private members

So, I only know of a two options, both equally ugly for different reasons:

1. Make the function public. This would be confusing to someone looking at the class, as they would think *myFunc()* might be something they could use externally even though they should not.
2. Call one of the few public methods that *MyClass* offers in a way that results in *myFunc()* being called, and look at the results. For several reasons, this is a mess. This requires significantly more setup in the test because those methods do more than just what *myFunc()* does. It also means if there was an issue elsewhere in the code, it could result in *myFunc()*'s test failing, even if it is actually fine. Finally, I might need to add additional public methods to retrieve the state of the class so I know enough to say whether *myFunc()* worked correctly or not - so in the end I'm adding more public methods that no-one else should be calling anyways.

C++ has the concept of `friend`, but as this is just a .cpp file with many
`BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE` inside, there is no class to befriend.

I'm sure others have run into this before when using Boost for testing. What other solutions are there?

Comment: With all due respect, testing implementation details (privates) is testing done wrong. It's the wrong sort of separation for units (what unit testing is about). Test the behavior of the class, and choose test cases that exercise that private member.  Use coverage tools to pin point those. Then if you need change the implementation details, the tests still convey a meaning.

Comment: Personally, I disagree.

This makes the unit tests quite bloated in size in our case, harder to maintain if the code changes, slower to run, and in the end requires more unnecessary public methods to fetch the state I would need to check if the results are right.

I think tests are a good place to "bend" the rules of convention at least a little, as they aren't a part of the main code.